# Creating a blank plot with a border in r

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a empty plot that has a green border. Essentially just creating a green box, I know how to make the plot blank but I am having trouble creating the box around the plot.

```
p2 <- plot(0,type='n', axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, lty='solid', col='green')
print(p2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create the empty plot using

```
plot(0, type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
```

and then draw the box using the function `box`:

```
box(col = "green")
```

Comment: In my case, I am trying to create a box with an if statement, so it would look like.                                                                          
if(x<.33){slide<-addPlot(slide,
fun=function() {print(p2)},vector.graphic=T,box(lty = 'solid', col='green'),offx=1,offy=.5,width=1,height=1)}

Comment: I guess the command would look something like this: `if (x < .33){slide <- addPlot(slide, fun=function(){plot(0,type='n',axes=FALSE); box(col = "green")}, vector.graphic = TRUE, offx = 1, offy = .5, width = 1, height = 1)}
`

Answer (score 2):

please try `rect` to control the boarder's color

```
plot(0,type='n',axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
u <- par("usr")
rect(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[4], border = "green")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want.  The solutions of @ikop and @mutian are good if you want a green line around your plot.  I have the idea that you want the *margins* to be green. If so,  here is a way to get that.  Just for fun,  I put a normal curve in the plot.

```
par(bg = 'darkgreen')
plot(0, type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE, 
    xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(0,0.5))
rect(par("usr")[1],par("usr")[3],par("usr")[2],par("usr")[4],col = "white")
curve(dnorm, xlim=c(-3,3), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Normal curve with green margins]